# How do I assign dedicated ip address to subdirectory of domain?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, ip, subdomain, subdirectory

I have domain hosted in dream host and my DNS provider is godaddy; now I have a custom application running under digital ocean which has a dedicated IP address.

Now consider my website is www.example.com and an ip address 14.181.162.226.

How do i point www.example.com/sub to 14.181.162.226

Comment: Your server has a dedicated IP address. It is not assigned per domain or part thereof.

Comment: hi @MikeRockett Thanks for your answer ! Can pls elaborate if you don't mind

Comment: Domains point to IP addresses, not folders. Because your domain points to a server with a dedicated IP address, *any* request made to that domain will be served by the same IP.

Comment: I see you have edited your question. What do you mean you want to forward the IP?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry @MikeRockett its again framed wrong . . . The question is  How do i point www.example.com/sub to 14.181.162.226

Comment: You're not reading my comments properly. IP addresses are assigned to the **server/account**, so example.com/sub is **already** pointing to the IP. What happens when you go to http://14.181.162.226/sub? Also, see [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+dedicated+IP%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for the definition of a dedicated IP.

Comment: Yeah I understand that example.com/sub is already pointing to an IP .  . www.example.com is hosted in dream host 
The IP 14.181.162.226 is my digitalocean servers IP
Is there a possibility that I could point my domain www.example.com/sub  that is currently hosted in dream host to 14.181.162.226 (digitalocean servers IP) 

Thanks for hearing me in patience

Comment: *Right*, I am so sorry - totally misread your question. Apologies for that. I don't think that is possible, I'm afraid. The only thing I could suggest is using `mod_proxy` to do this, but you would need to point it to the domain used on your Digital Ocean server. If you're not using a domain there, then I'm afraid you're out of luck (so far as I know). You would be better off pointing a subdomain to the other server.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm wrong - you may be able to achieve this with `.htaccess`. See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/364019/rewrite-ip-address-of-a-host-to-another-ip-address-with-htaccess) for information. Be sure to read the information in the answer provided carefully.

Comment: Sure Mike Thanks I'll take a look on that and try executing it and will get back.

Also to mention the digital ocean server is assigned to a sub domain sub.example.com which I'm planning to change to example.com/sub (subdirectory instead of subdomain for my domino's ranking and traffic building)